# Java MySQL deadlock (multithreading)

Tags: java, mysql, multithreading, deadlock

I'm getting this weird deadlock and I can't quite figure out why it occurs

If two threads call this one method at about the same time, I get this exception:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction
```

This is the method

```
public void saveItems(List<Pair<Item, MapleInventoryType>> items, int id) throws             SQLException {
    synchronized (this) {
        PreparedStatement ps = null;
        PreparedStatement pse = null;
        try {
            StringBuilder query = new StringBuilder();
            query.append("DELETE FROM `inventoryitems` WHERE `type` = ? AND `");
            query.append(account ? "accountid" : "characterid").append("` = ?");
            Connection con = DatabaseConnection.getConnection();
            ps = con.prepareStatement(query.toString());
            ps.setInt(1, value);
            ps.setInt(2, id);
            ps.executeUpdate(); //DEADLOCK OCCURS HERE
            ps.close();

            for (Pair<Item, MapleInventoryType> pair : items) {
                Item item = pair.getLeft();
                MapleInventoryType mit = pair.getRight();
                ps = con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO `inventoryitems` VALUES (DEFAULT, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)", Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
                ps.setInt(1, value);
                ps.setString(2, account ? null : String.valueOf(id));
                ps.setString(3, account ? String.valueOf(id) : null);
                ps.setInt(4, item.getItemId());
                ps.setInt(5, mit.getType());
                ps.setInt(6, item.getPosition());
                ps.setInt(7, item.getQuantity());
                ps.setString(8, item.getOwner());
                ps.setInt(9, item.getPetId());
                ps.setInt(10, item.getFlag());
                ps.setLong(11, item.getExpiration());
                ps.setString(12, item.getGiftFrom());
                ps.executeUpdate();

                if (mit.equals(MapleInventoryType.EQUIP) || mit.equals(MapleInventoryType.EQUIPPED)) {
                    pse = con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO `inventoryequipment` VALUES (DEFAULT, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
                    try (ResultSet rs = ps.getGeneratedKeys()) {

                        if (!rs.next()) {
                            throw new RuntimeException("Inserting item failed.");
                        }

                        pse.setInt(1, rs.getInt(1));
                    }
                    ps.close();

                    Equip equip = (Equip) item;
                    pse.setInt(2, equip.getUpgradeSlots());
                    pse.setInt(3, equip.getLevel());
                    pse.setInt(4, equip.getStr());
                    pse.setInt(5, equip.getDex());
                    pse.setInt(6, equip.getInt());
                    pse.setInt(7, equip.getLuk());
                    pse.setInt(8, equip.getHp());
                    pse.setInt(9, equip.getMp());
                    pse.setInt(10, equip.getWatk());
                    pse.setInt(11, equip.getMatk());
                    pse.setInt(12, equip.getWdef());
                    pse.setInt(13, equip.getMdef());
                    pse.setInt(14, equip.getAcc());
                    pse.setInt(15, equip.getAvoid());
                    pse.setInt(16, equip.getHands());
                    pse.setInt(17, equip.getSpeed());
                    pse.setInt(18, equip.getJump());
                    pse.setInt(19, 0);
                    pse.setInt(20, equip.getVicious());
                    pse.setInt(21, equip.getItemLevel());
                    pse.setInt(22, equip.getItemExp());
                    pse.setInt(23, equip.getRingId());
                    pse.executeUpdate();
                    pse.close();
                }
            }
        } finally {
            if (ps != null) {
                ps.close();
            }
            if (pse != null) {
                pse.close();
            }
        }
}
```

I don't understand how the deadlock could occur since everything is wrapped inside the synchronized block.

Help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your transaction isolation level.

Did you set autoCommit() to false ? If true, then when you're running in transaction's context,  you need to commit it after work, because, if your transaction isolation level is strong as `Repeatable Read`, then Lock is on active transaction's context until commit occurs.

Give us more details about what you're doing.

Comment: Right, autoCommit was the name of this thing. +1

Comment: autoCommit is enabled

Comment: You know what actually, I just realized my issue. From the context where this method is called, autoCommit is turned off to be able to rollback.

Answer (score 0):

> I don't understand how the deadlock could occur since everything is wrapped inside the synchronized block.

You may have e.g. another process/thread doing e.g. an INSERT in the same table. Depending on how your DB is configured you may get this exception which you're getting. The synchronized block here just means that no other Java thread can call/enter into this same block of code at the same time. This doesn't prevent the same DB resource table/page/record (on the DB level) from being accessed by another process/thread at the same time.

Comment: Try adding some println statements before // DEADLOCK OCCURS HERE and before all other places where you access your table and see which one of your threads is doing what. Also, check if the first thread has committed the DB transaction when the second one starts accessing the DB resources... But your problem is not that 2 threads are inside the synchronized block at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that you're not calling close() on your Connection.  Try using this in place of your finally { } block.  Hope this helps.

```
    finally {
        if (ps != null) ps.close();
        if (pse != null) pse.close();
        if (con != null) con.close();
    }
```

Comment: The connection is reused later so I don't close it yet

Answer (score 0):

You are accessing inventoryitems before inventoryequipment. There might be another thread doing this in the opposite order, leading to a deadlock.

You should always have a hierarchy of locks and only access locked resources in the same order.

Why don't you use ps.close() directly after ps.executeUpdate(); but after a complicated if statement? If you need to use values from ps in pse, you should store them in variables between.